# Jira: Add new version via REST

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

I've been trying to do this via REST using bash in linux and am using the following:

```
curl -u${USERNAME}:${PASSWORD} -X POST "http://localhost:8088/rest/api/2/version" -d "{\"fields\": {\"name\": \"1.1\", \"projectId\": 10000, \"id\": \"10002\" }}"
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?
I don't get any response.

And when I do the following:

```
curl -s -u${USERNAME}:${PASSWORD} -X GET "http://localhost:8088/rest/api/2/project/SW/versions" | jq
```

I see no new data.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was in the details:

```
curl -u${USERNAME}:${PASSWORD} -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST "http://localhost:8088/rest/api/2/version" -d "{\"name\": \"1.1\", \"projectId\": \"10000\", \"id\": \"10002\" }"
```

It needed the headers set and some improvements to the json being sent!